# Método finaliza sua execução inesperadamente ao chamar outro método

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, windows-service

Estou implementando um método que realiza uma chamada a um outro método que deveria retornar um `IEnumerable<TEntidade>`. Contudo, no retorno desta lista o método que iniciou a chamada simplesmente finaliza sua execução sem continuar a ler o código a seguir.

Depurando, consigo acessar o valor da variável query dentro do escopo do método Listar.

Segue abaixo código exemplo. Após a linha `var x = Listar();` o código finaliza sua execução.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
      //Some code here
      var x = Listar();
      //Some code here
}


public IEnumerable<ModelEntities> Listar()
{
    var _c = new SMSEntities();
    var query = //query Linq
               select new ModelEntities
               {
                     //inicializando campos
               };
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou fazer debugging com uso de breakpoints?

Comment: @mutlei, a depuração que citei no código é utilizando breakpoints.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `printf`s (ou o equivalente em C#, que eu desconheço) em partes do código para saber por onde ele passa?

Comment: Sim. Ao finalizar a execução do método Listar, ele finaliza a execução do método DoSomething

Comment: Há alguma excepção a ser lançada? já viste no Event Viewer do windows?

Comment: Exceção explicita não é lançada. Eu inclusive consigo visualizar os dados da query. Se eu der um tolist dentro do metodo Listar eu tenho a lista de objetos do banco de dados. Vou verificar agora no event viewer

Comment: Retornei o EF6 para EF5 e o código funcionou sem nenhum problema. Vou manter a pergunta porque não encontrei ainda a explicação para tal, talvez incompatibilidade com o WindowsService.

Comment: Rebaixar a versão do EF não faz o menor sentido... provavelmente existe algum outro problema, que não é possível ver, fora do código postado.

Comment: Ao trabalhar com métodos assíncronos (i.e. `async`/`await`) é muito comum esse tipo de interrupção misteriosa do código. por exemplo, quando não se usa `await` para chamar um método `async`, ai você está debugando o corpo do método async, e após uma chamada await, nada da execução continuar... hehe... tipo já era né!

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, obrigado pela informação, muito útil. Contudo, não estava utilizando o recurso de métodos assincronos neste caso. Ainda não consegui relacionar o 'downgrade' do EF para solucionar o problema.

Comment: Já tentou retornar como tipo anônimo?

Answer (score 2):

Isto aqui não devolve um `IEnumerable<ModelEntities>`:

```
var query = //query Linq
           select new ModelEntities
           {
                 //inicializando campos
           };
return query;
```

Isto devolve um `IQueryable`. O `return` nem chega a executar a query propriamente dita, e é por isso que você não vê erros.

Para devolver `IEnumerable` você precisa mudar o `return`:

```
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Cigano, eu postei a pergunta original, mas antes de a fazer havia tentado de diversas formas, inclusive utilizando o ToList(), e ainda assim o erro persistia.

Comment: @Vinícius Na verdade não entendi o objetivo deste código. Ele é devolvido onde?

Comment: No método DoSomething, ele executa o metodo Listar() que retorna uma lista de clientes aos quais serão enviados SMS no próprio método DoSomething. 

Como comentei acima, retornando a versão do EF para 5 o mesmo código compilou e rodou normalmente.

Comment: @Vinícius, vc está usando algum tipo de LazyLoading na sua aplicação? Caso esteja, você pode estar disparando esse LazyLoad e o Entity estar mal configurado.